# Firebase Auth UI with Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've followed [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/authenticating-a-vue-js-application-with-firebase-ui-8870a3a5cff8) tutorial to create a vue component for login users with firebase Auth UI. but I keep getting an error in console. I've used firebase pre-built UI using its cdn in non-vue project before and it worked. but I can't figure out the way of implementing it with vueJS. any help?

source code userLogin.vue component :

```
<template>
  <div id="userLogin">
    <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
      <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" style="margin-top:200px;"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import firebase from '../firebaseInit'

export default {
  name: 'userLogin',
  data() {
      return {
      }
  },
   mounted() {
    var uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/success',
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ]
      };
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    }
}
</script>
```

here is the error :

```
`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER_ID' of undefined"

found in

---> <UserLogin> at src\components\userLogin.vue
       <App> at src\App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:576
logError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1729
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1724
handleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1713
callHook @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2912
insert @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4086
invokeInsertHook @ vue.esm.js?efeb:5853
patch @ vue.esm.js?efeb:6072
Vue._update @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2652
updateComponent @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2780
get @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3130
Watcher @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3119
mountComponent @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2787
Vue$3.$mount @ vue.esm.js?efeb:8407
Vue$3.$mount @ vue.esm.js?efeb:10747
Vue._init @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4559
Vue$3 @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4648
(anonymous) @ main.js?3479:17
./src/main.js @ app.js:6169
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:679
fn @ app.js:89
0 @ app.js:6194
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:679
(anonymous) @ app.js:725
(anonymous) @ app.js:728
vue.esm.js?efeb:1733 TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER_ID' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mounted (userLogin.vue?e569:23)
    at callHook (vue.esm.js?efeb:2910)
    at Object.insert (vue.esm.js?efeb:4086)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.esm.js?efeb:5853)
    at Vue$3.patch [as __patch__] (vue.esm.js?efeb:6072)
    at Vue$3.Vue._update (vue.esm.js?efeb:2652)
    at Vue$3.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2780)
    at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:3130)
    at new Watcher (vue.esm.js?efeb:3119)
    at mountComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2787)
```

node version : v8.9.4

Comment: I think you should provide the (formatted) sourcecode, that leads to this error.

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis sorry, I added it now

Comment: Well done! This will greatly improve the odds someone could help you :-)

Comment: @DulanHewage what firebase version are you using?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 3.17.4

Comment: update to 4.9.1 please and try it @DulanHewage

Comment: @PeterHaddad could you please tell me the command for updating?

Comment: @PeterHaddad in index.html?? then how can I use it in vue component?

Comment: @DulanHewage are you not using this https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire?

Comment: @PeterHaddad no, I'm using npm firebase package

Comment: Did you import firebase/auth component? Try use this one to import: import * as firebase from 'firebase';

Comment: @TiWang this is my firebaseInit.js 

`import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default firebaseApp`

Comment: Can you try to add import * as firebase from 'firebase' in your firebaseinit file?

Comment: Any update about it ?